# Bathroom over sink lighting bar

Tags: light-fixture

I have a newer stainless three bulb light bar over my sink, and one of the lights single glass shades keeps loosening up and wants to fall off,only the bulb keeps it from doing so. The retaining ring will not screw on to the ceramic socket tight enough, it's very loose, I tried another ring from the other two lights and they are the same way but they seem to fit ok on the other lights, as I can tighten them up correctly and I'v had no problem. I have the clear bulbs in them and they do get really hot, could this be a problem, if so I'll opt for a newer type bulb. Do they make a smaller ring for these sockets to tighten them more securely?
Leonce

Comment: Does the retaining ring screw all the way onto the socket, or are only a few of the threads actually overlapping the socket? If possible, try reversing the ring and screwing it on "upside down"… it might just work better that way.

Comment: Actually I tried both ways, the ring is flat washer like on one side and a lip on the other,I was told that the lip side is for up against the glass shade.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound a bit weird but I have used colored modeling clay to tighten up the ceramic rings that were loose. The heat from the fixture sets the clay and it wont come out. So If it doesn't look right take it apart and wipe it down before the clay has time to dry. Also make sure your lamps are not a higher wattage than the fixture is rated for. Last can you hear a buzzing in that 1 lamp? I have had a few over the years that the element in the lamp must not have been supported correctly and they made an audible buzz. This could be a source of vibration but it is rare (changing the lamp would solve the problem if it was buzzing).

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with threaded socket bases. The retention rings and the bases are sometimes out of spec and will stay loose or even slip the threads when tightened. A trick I learned while apprenticing was to use a high temperature(some work up to 650 F) thread locker. You can get it from just about any auto parts store. Remove the light, disassemble the retaining ring and shade, apply the thread lock(follow the directions for install and cure times). Then reassemble and reinstall the light. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thread locker will help if it has a close tolerance but if sloppy like the OP suggest thread locker has no volume to fill the spaces.

Comment: That's true in a few cases. Portfolio fixtures are notorious for this. Most, though, have just about 1/16" wiggle that the thread locker can give just enough bite to tighten it up. Also, the usual culprit, from my experience, for loose retaining rings is heat build-up. Most fixtures have a 60W maximum per bulb holder. Down-sizing to 40W or switching to LED bulbs helps greatly.

Comment: Ya I think I'll either try some high heat silicon which has plenty of volume to fill the gap or just try a led or mercury florescent type bulb. I have the same fixture over my toilet except it's a single bulb and I have a florescent bulb in it and had no problem, but it sticks out like a sore thumb. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score -2):

How about Teflon tape??   I found it to really hold nice on those crappy ceramic rings.

Comment: How does it hold up to the heat from an incandescent bulb?